# How to search within a vimscript function

Tags: vimscript, search

I'm trying to write a vimscript function that will search for a ruby class definition. My function correctly goes to the top of the file to start the search, but then doesn't move to the given class definition.  To simplify, I tried searching with:

```
normal! 1G
normal! /class<CR>
```

but this failed. It just moved to the top of the file.

My more complete code is

```
:function! GotoClass(className)
    " Move to the top of the current buffer
    normal! 1G
    normal! /class\s\+ . a:className<CR>
:endfunction

" Create the keybinding
nnoremap <leader>gtoc :call GotoClass(input('Class name: '))<CR>
```

Comment: please use the `search()` function.

Comment: The reason why your code is not working is that `:normal!` will not recognize `<CR>` as a "return" character. You can work around that by using `:execute "normal! /class\<CR>"` instead. In your actual example, you're trying to do some concatenation (with `. a:className`) so you need to use a string anyways, another reason to use `:execute`. But as Christian pointed out, `search()` is better. See `:help :execute` and `:help search()` for all the details.

Answer (score 3):

FWIW, this looks a lot like a job for the built-in `:help definition-search` but, for some reason, the default ftplugin for Ruby doesn't set `:help 'define'`, which is crucial for this feature to work.

Let's fix that by creating `after/ftplugin/ruby.vim` and populating it with the following line:

```
setlocal define=\^\\s\*\\(class\\\|def\\\|module\\)
```

which essentially tells Vim to look for lines that start with either `class`, `def`, or `module` as cues when searching for "definitions".

Once that is done, we can simply leverage the built-in `:help :djump`:

```
:dj Annotation
```

or even:

```
:dj annotation
```

if `:help 'ignorecase'` is on.

[image: djump]

And, if you really want a mapping (though `:dj`  compares quite well to your `<leader>gtoc`), you can go with a very simple:

```
nnoremap <key> :djump<Space>
```

---

Bonus: you also get `[D` and friends.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start by removing those useless colons:

```
function! GotoClass(className)
    normal! 1G
    normal! /class\s\+ . a:className<CR>
endfunction
nnoremap <key> :call GotoClass(input('Class name: '))<CR>
```

Now, the most obvious issue is that `:help :normal` can't do concatenation.

The following line literally searches for `class`, followed by one or more whitespace characters, followed by a space, followed by any character except `\n`, followed by a space, followed by `a:className<CR>`:

```
normal! /class\s\+ . a:className<CR>
```

which is unlikely to find any match, which explains why your function only moves the cursor to the top of the buffer. Also, the `<CR>` is useless in this context.

A simple fix would be to use `:help :execute`, which does concatenation:

```
function! GotoClass(className)
    normal! 1G
    execute "normal! /class\s\+" . a:className
endfunction
nnoremap <key> :call GotoClass(input('Class name: '))<CR>
```

But we can do better. Instead of abusing `:normal`, which doesn't really add any value here, let's use `:help :/` to replace these two lines:

```
normal! 1G
execute "normal! /class\s\+" . a:className
```

with a single line:

```
function! GotoClass(className)
    execute "1/class\s\+" . a:className
endfunction
nnoremap <key> :call GotoClass(input('Class name: '))<CR>
```

Let's not stop there! Is that custom function really necessary? We could use `:help search()` and get rid of it:

```
nnoremap <key> <Cmd>1call search('class\s\+' . input('Class name: '))<CR>
```

[image: search]

---

At this point I wanted to go even further with `:help searchdecl()`, which would have allowed me to get rid of concatenation, but it proved to be a lot less reliable than I expected so I'm afraid I reached the end of the line.